# WPF MVVM: Prismv4 -- Is it necessary to use the Microsoft Async CTP if you use this?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Basically, I was wondering if it's necessary (or better) to use the Microsoft Async CTP if you plan to use Prismv4. I know when I was skimming over the features of Prismv4 I found something about Asynchronous binding, but I wasn't sure if it was something baked into Prismv4 or the old way of creating threads and the such.

Comment: Retagged: Async CTP is different from Microsoft Sync Framework.  The former is the preview update to the compiler, the latter is a set of libraries for synchronizing data across different sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe these are related.  The Asynchronous Binding in Prism 4 doesn't use this capability.